# Find duplicate keywords in paragraphs in two text files using Python and list the results (compare them) in a new text file

Tags: python, regex, duplicates, compare

I'm trying to create a code (it's not completed, because I don't know how to progress - I'm a beginner in programming) that would find duplicate keywords in paragraphs and compare these paragraphs in a new text file. Here is an example of contents of the text files:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------

File Creation Date:            September 07, 2004
Identifier #:                  hf8594.tif
Image Pixels (meters):         1.25
Format:                        8 bit TIFF

------------------------------------------------------------------

File Creation Date:            December 13, 2004
Identifier #:                  ha8421.tif
Image Pixels (meters):         5.25
Format:                        8 bit TIFF

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Each of the text file contains about 200 of these paragraphs and some of the `Identifiers` are same in both files. My aim is to find same identifiers in the two textfiles and compare `File Creation Date, Image Pixels (meters) and Format` (all lines separated by hyphens) in a new text file (or excel sheet might be better, because of the columns).

Here is a draft of my code

```
# importing a library
import re

file1=open("file1.txt","r")
file2=open("file2.txt","r")
list1 = file1.readlines()
list2 = file2.readlines()

paragraph_sep = "------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
paragraphs = paragraph_str.split(paragraph_sep)[1:]

s = 'Identifier #:             ha8421.tif'
comp = re.compile("Identifier #: \s* (.*tif)")
a = re.search(comp, s)
a.groups()
=> ('ha8421.tif',)

def get_id_from_string(s):
    ids = re.search(comp, s)
    return ids[0]
```

I'm trying to identify the key word that is going to be used for finding duplicates (in this case `something.tif` - that's why I'm using regex) and set each paragraph according to divider (the hyphens). This is the output I would like to get might look like this in txt file:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
    file1.txt

    File Creation Date:            September 07, 2004
    Identifier #:                  hf8594.tif
    Image Pixels (meters):         1.25
    Format:                        8 bit TIFF

    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    file2.txt

    File Creation Date:            December 01, 2004
    Identifier #:                  hf8594.tif
    Image Pixels (meters):         1.30
    Format:                        8 bit TIFF

    ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or ideally in excel sheet, so the results would be split in columns - for example like this:

```
                              file1.txt               file2.txt

    File Creation Date:       September 07, 2004      December 01, 2004
    Identifier #:             hf8594.tif              hf8594.tif
    Image Pixels (meters):    1.25                    1.30
    Format:                   8 bit TIFF              8 bit TIFF
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you expect?

Comment: ok, I update my question

Comment: I've also updated names of the files, so it should make more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

ok, assuming in some strings you have

```
L:hhtk\hf8594.txt

File Creation Date:            December 01, 2004
Identifier #:                  hf8594.tif
Image Pixels (meters):         1.30
Format:                        8 bit TIFF
```

(new lines are there too)
you can get say the Identifier with a regular expression like:

```
def get_id(parastr):
     a = re.search(ur'(?<=Identifier #:)(?:\s*)(?P<id>\S*)(?=\n)', paragraphstr)
     return a.group('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a dict with each file:

```
with open(fn) as f1:
    di={}
    for block in re.finditer(r'^[-]{60,}\n(.*?)(?=^[-]{60,}|\Z)', f1.read(), re.S | re.M):
        d={k:v.strip() for k, v in [b.split(':') for b in block.group(1).strip().splitlines()]}
        di[d['Identifier #']]=[d.get(k) for k in ('File Creation Date', 'Image Pixels (meters)', 'Format')]

>>> di
{'hf8594.tif': ['September 07, 2004', '1.25', '8 bit TIFF'], 'ha8421.tif': ['December 13, 2004', '5.25', '8 bit TIFF']}
```

Then use those two dictionaries to compare each list to the keyed ID. This assumes that the file entries are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

My totally regex-free solution... because regex is cool but too much... and you will get fat.

```
from collections import defaultdict
separator = '------------------------------------------------------------------'
files = ["file1.txt","file2.txt"]
images = defaultdict(list)

for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        data = [item.strip() for item in f.read().strip().split(separator) if item.strip()]

    for item in data:
        fcd, id, ip, fmt = [line.strip() for line in item.split("\n")]
        images[id.split(":")[1].strip()].append([file, fcd, id, ip, fmt])

with open("duplicates.txt", "w") as f:
    for id in images:
        if len(images[id]) > 1:
            f.write(separator + "\n")
            for duplicate in images[id]:
                f.write("{}\n\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n\n".format(*duplicate))
                f.write(separator + "\n")
```